# Two or more occurrence of at least one in character set with PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to make PHP regex to find if text has two or more of at least one character in character set {-, l, s, i, a}.
I made like this.

```
preg_match("/[-lisa]{2,}/", $text);
```

But this doesn't work.
Please help me.

Comment: You can use a capture group for the character class with a backreference `\1` to make sure to match the same char at least once.

Comment: Dont think char class can be used for that. maybe `(l|i|s|a|-){2,}`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I had that thought as well but that requires 3 matches, or I'm wrong. Is `([-lisa])\1{2,}` what you thought as well?

Comment: I thought something like `^.*?([-lisa]).*?\1.*$` but maybe I am reading it wrong.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking needed to be next to each other. That seems like a better solution because it'll account for both.

Comment: @user3783243 (l|i|s|a|-){2,} is not working in the case of "-lisa". It looks ([-lisa])\1{2,} is correct. Am I right?

Comment: I might have misread. I thought you were trying to find occurrences of at least 2 of 1 char. `([-lisa])\1{2,}` i dont think is right at all. I think @Thefourthbird solution is what you'd actually want.  If not sample strings and defined behavior would help question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matching *two or more occurrences* means matching two is enough for the check to be valid.

*At least one in character set* might either mean you want to match the same char from the set or any of the chars in the set two times. If you want the former, when the same char repeats, you can use `preg_match('~([-lisa]).*?\1~', $string, $match)` (**note** the single quotes delimiting the string literal, if you use double quotes, the backreference must have double backslash), if the latter, i.e. you want to match `..l...i..`, you can use `preg_match('~[-lisa].*?[-lisa]~', $string, $match)` or `preg_match('~([-lisa]).*?(?1)~', $string, $match)` (where `(?1)` is a regex subroutine that repeats the corresponding group pattern).

If your strings contain line breaks, do not forget to add `s` modifier, `preg_match('~([-lisa]).*?\1~s', $string, $match)`.

More than that, if you want to check for *consecutive character repetition*, you should remove `.*` from the above patterns, i.e. 1) must be `preg_match('~([-lisa])\1~', $string, $match)` and 2) must be `preg_match('~[-lisa]{2}~', $string, $match)` (though, this is not what you want judging by your own feeback, so this example here is just for the record).

The `([-lisa])\1{2}` pattern that you find useful matches a *repeated* `-`, `l`, `i`, `s` or `a` char three times (`---`, `lll`, `sss`, etc.), thus only use it if it fits your requirements.

Note that `preg_match` functions searches for a match anywhere inside a string and does not require a full string match (thus, no need adding `.*` (or `^.*`, `.*$`) at the start and end of the pattern).

See a [sample regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/weEhoO/1), feel free to test your strings in this environment.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. By the way, I used like preg_match("/regex/", $string, $matches). How can I change your regex like upper pattern? Sincerely I am not familiar with your expression like '~expression~'. Is this same as "/expression/"?

Comment: @SlobodanDev See [*"Delimiters"*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).